# Horizontal center a span element

Tags: html, css, image, center

I'm using a span element to create a container for an image with a caption. I want to center the image on it's own line, just like I would center an image using  <center> and <img>.
When I use the span container with "float", it works, but as soon as I remove the "float" property the I can no longer set the span width.

```
    <span class="imageholder" style="width:150px">
<a href="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/37f4256f7c29a1b3335eb535e/images/62f05d38-ae67-40d1-bf14-7773330b8169.jpg" target="new"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/37f4256f7c29a1b3335eb535e/images/62f05d38-ae67-40d1-bf14-7773330b8169.jpg" width="100%" alt="Roux and Mary at the Good Food Festival"></a>
    <span class="caption" style="width:150px">Roux and Mary at the Good Food Festival
    </span>
</span>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbxuo76k/2/)
The top image is the result I am looking for, minus the container. The middle image shows the container with caption, using "float:left". The bottom image is the one I'm trying to center.

Thank you!

Comment: There seems to be only two images in the jsfiddle Adam. which one is the top middle and bottom image there??

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and is no longer used in HTML5. Also, extracting all the inline styling to a proper stylesheet would be helpful

Comment: `target="new"` should be `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` is an 'inline' element. You're attempting to treat it as a 'block-level' element. Adding `float: left;` forces it to become 'block-level', and then you can apply something like `width: 100%; text-align: center;` to center the image within. An alternative to `float: left;` is to set `display: inline-block;` on your span tag. This leaves you with much the same circumstance though... you'll need to add `width: 100%; text-align: center;` to center the nested image.

Comment: Why not use `<div>` instead of `<span>` then?

Comment: `<div>`s are block-level. I'd use a `<div>`. OP's question specifies using `<span>`.

Comment: I'd also use `<div>`, but you're right, post is about `<span>`.

Comment: Using `<div>` instead of `<span>` was the answer. I've not really gotten me head around the difference between inline and block-level elements yet. Thanks!